# retain release common practice in iOS setter methods

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

The common practice in IOS setters is the following:

```
- (void)setMyString:(NSString *)newString {
    if ( newString != myString ) {
        [myString release];
        myString = [newString retain];
    }
}
```

On the contrary this is not good practice

```
- (void)setMyString:(NSString *)newString {
    if ( myString != nil ) [myString release];
        myString = [newString retain];
    }
}
```

What is the reason checking for equality in the first case? What is the problem in the seconds case?

Comment: @Till Not really. See the answer below.

Comment: just courious, why not use regular iOS properties? why do you need setters

Comment: String properties are normally declared as `copy` not `retain`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is somewhat redundant, but...

If the new and old object are the same then you send `release` to the old object and it gets deallocated, the pointer to the new object will become a dangling pointer as the object it pointed to will no longer exist (since it pointed to the same object as the old object pointer). Ex. if `myString` and `newString` point to the same instance who has a retain count of one, then you subtract one, it'll equal zero. it's too late to add one now, because it'll get deallocated. However, reverse the calls to `retain` and `release` and it should be fine. If the retain count is one and you add one, it's now two, and you can safely send release. In general, I'd say before you disown an object, assert ownership of the new one first.

Also, the first type of setter would be what you would use for `retain`/`strong` style setter. If it were `assign` you wouldn't need to retain/release as no ownership is supposed to be asserted. NSStrings often have a `copy` style setter which copies the argument and uses that, which would create a copy instead of retaining. I would generally use `copy` for anything with a mutable subclass as you wouldn't want someone passing in a NSMutableString and mutating it behind your back. [This page](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/06/assign-retain-copy-pitfalls-in-obj-c.html) goes into accessors, and you'll notice that they retain the new value before releasing the old one, and explain why.

Answer (score 2):

If you set something like this `[object setMyString:[object myString]];` without checking for equality - it will be crash! Because it will be released before you send it message retain. (in case when only object own string). Also in first example we checking for equality to avoid extra operations.

Comment: +1, though you should change the order of your sentences - the question of the ownership is far more important than simply avoiding an extra setter call.

Comment: @user1090590 so what is the rule? First retain and the release?

Comment: I don't think there is a "rule". Most people seem to do it as in your first example. Anyway, did you consider using ARC?

Comment: >> so what is the rule? First retain and the release? it depends on what type of setter do you need. (assign, retain, copy)

Answer (score 0):

You may take this to though the memory management, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/.